# cloud run not auto deploying?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a strange problem. I setup continous delivery for cloud run when I commit to a specific dev branch of my github code.

When I commit, I see it notices the change and builds the code but it does not automatically deploy it to the cloud run instance.

I have to manually select edit and deploy new revision then select the image that was created.

What can I do to automatically deploy?

Comment: Do you have a build step that deploys to Cloud Run? If yes, review the logs for error messages. Your question does not have enough details to help you debug this problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for replying John. I do not have build steps. In my cloud run function gui, I just clicked on continuous deployment and pointed it to my github branch. When there is a change cloud run does recognize it and I see it being built using cloud build. It's just not deploying automatically. Where can I access the build steps? I am using a docker file to build and my changes are building successfully.

Comment: Review the logs in Cloud Logging for your Cloud Run service.

Comment: @JohnHanley I do not see anything. When I click on build logs it takes me to cloud build where I see that completing successfully. But for cloud run, I do not see anything related to deployment, nor do I see it in the revision history, and I test the current cloud run and it did not automatically deploy even though it built the new code.

Comment: There are logs for just about everything. Suggestion. Create a new service following this document. If this works, compare configurations: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build As written your question does not have the details required to solve your problem. I can only guess and provide tips.

Comment: @JohnHanley I created a new service but it is also not working oddly. It still triggers the build, but does not deploy automatically and I have to select it manually as revision each time. Is there something I need to search to see deployment logs?

Comment: @JohnHanley I found the answer(from another one of your answers), I didn't realize I need a cloudbuild.yaml file. I took it off a doc you shared and it worked.

Comment: Post an answer with that detail and the cloudbuild.yaml. I am interested in following up with the details from your solution.

Comment: @JohnHanley Sure. Done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. [Documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run)

I think the problem was that cloud build continuous deployment setup automates the building when a change is detected in my github repo but it didn't actually deploy the image it built.

I had to create a file called `cloudbuild.yaml` and save this file(updated for my cloud run instance)

```
 steps:
 # Build the container image
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE-NAME:$COMMIT_SHA', '.']
 # Push the container image to Container Registry
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
   args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE-NAME:$COMMIT_SHA']
 # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
 - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
   entrypoint: gcloud
   args:
   - 'run'
   - 'deploy'
   - 'SERVICE-NAME'
   - '--image'
   - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE-NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
   - '--region'
   - 'REGION'
 images:
 - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE-NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
```